# How can I limit the words coming out of SOLR search result in TYPO3?

Tags: search, solr, typo3

I have a working SOLR search in my TYPO3 installation.
How can I limit the content length or character limit in search results?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation : https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Templating#CROP

```
###CROP:###RESULT_DOCUMENT.CONTENT###|length###
```

Comment: Thanku for the answer, I am already using >plugin.tx_solr.viewhelpers.crop.maxLength = 50
>plugin.tx_solr.viewhelpers.crop.cropIndicator = ...

Comment: It still doesn't crop the content.